# Case created from NetSuite API not triggering send email for saved search

Tags: netsuite

We want to send an email to our pager system when a support case is created. I created a saved search for a case which would send an email upon case creation. When cases are created using the UI or support form built out of Netsuite, the email is sent correctly. But in most cases our customers submit cases through our website, which uses an API to create a ticket on NetSuite. In this case, although a new record is created on the saved search, an email is not sent. Is there a way to make this work in Netsuite without working on the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the NetSuite Help:

> ***Important:*** To improve performance and avoid unnecessary email, by default email alerts are not sent for updates made by CSV imports or Web services integrations. To cause email alerts to be sent for CSV imports and Web services integrations, an account administrator or another user with the *Set Up Company* permission can set the *Enable Email Alerts for WS and CSV Imports* preference at **Setup > Company > Printing, Fax & Email Preferences**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly configure your NetSuite Case Management. If this is properly configure then you don't need to extend the NS API just to create a ticket. Check out from NetSuite Suite Answers: "Setting Up Support Checklist"

Now, the reason why customer is not getting the email when they created a ticket is because they are Anonymous which means NS does not have a way to identify the customer(unless they create the ticket from the customer center). NS uses a default anonymous customer which is configured from the Case Profile. The way to correct this is create a script on before submit that will check the email address that was on the case against the list of the customer records once there is a match then you set the Company Field of the case to the matching record. Now the case has the customer record and a notification will be sent out to the customer.

If you will not do this NS will send the email to the anonymous customer configured in the Case Profile.

BTW: you don't need to have a saved search to achieve what you want.